# Installing drain saddle for Reverse Osmosis (RO) system in brass metal pipes

Tags: sink, water-filtration, p-trap

I am trying to install a reverse osmosis RO system under the kitchen sink. The pipes are all metal (brass, I suppose but not sure). where can I install the drain saddle?

The instructions with the RO system and online videos/PDF all assume that the pipes are plastic/PVC etc. Is it OK to drill that 1/4" hole in the metal pipe or will the pipe be too thin and not hold the drain pipe properly?

Thanks much!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine to install it on a metal pipe.

Drill the hole on the top of the horizontal drain between the garbage disposal and main sink.

If you have problems for some reason, or are still worried about it not being plastic, then replace that one metal pipe with a plastic one.

Comment: Thanks @Dotes. I did drill a hole before your message though in the horizontal straight line (not the top part of the drain). Luckily no leak so far :-)